# Как расшифровать trail файлы Oracle Golden Gate?

Tags: oracle

Есть настроенная репликация через Oracle Golden Gate. Как или чем самостоятельно прочитать существующие Trail файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для просмотра trail файлов используют стандартную утилиту оракла, logdump. Этой утилитой вы можете просмотреть транзакции и записи, статистику по ним и сохранить содержимое trail файла в другой файл.
Вот тут подробно расписано как открыть и прочитать trail файлы GG http://www.ateam-oracle.com/oracle-goldengate-logdump/

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь публиковать развернутые ответы содержащие конкретный пример минимального решения, дополняя их ссылкой на источник. Ответы–ссылки (как и комментарии) не добавляют знаний в Рунет.